# Kibana_system unable to authenticate elastic user

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have encountered an issue I don't know how to solve.

I have installed elasticsearch and kibana version 8.7.1 locally, and I've created certificates by following this guide:
https://quachtd.com/configure-https-for-elasticsearch/

And https works fine with elasticsearch.

This is my elasticsearch.yaml file:

```
cluster.name: my-application
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication: required
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: http.p12
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

And this is my kibana.yaml file:

```
    elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
    elasticsearch.password: "3tWlx_uMNAemfyh5YUN="
    elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ["C:\\kibana-8.7.1\\config\\elasticsearch-ca.pem"]
```

The .pem file is in the specified config folder. However when I start kibana and try to navigate to it I get this error in the console:

```
[2023-05-25T12:18:10.127+02:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception
        Root causes:
                security_exception: unable to authenticate user [kibana_system] for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]
```

But I can authenticate the user via curl:

```
$ curl -u kibana_system:3tWlx_uMNAemfyh5YUN= -k https://localhost:9200/_security/_authenticate
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   273  100   273    0     0   1418      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1421{"username":"kibana_system","roles":["kibana_system"],"full_name":null,"email":null,"metadata":{"_reserved":true},"enabled":true,"authentication_realm":{"name":"reserved","type":"reserved"},"lookup_realm":{"name":"reserved","type":"reserved"},"authentication_type":"realm"}
```

If anyone have any ideas that could help me I'd greatly appreciate it.